# Lightning Change Event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is there a way to catch the change event of a particular field/component? I saw on the AuraDocs that there is a valueChange event but trying to handle it makes the app throw an error on load. I was wondering if I could build some automatic field validation / search suggestions without relying on other js libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a complete example that does what I think you were attempting to do:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="expenseName" type="String" default="My Expense"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.expenseName}" action="{!c.expenseNameChanged}"/>     

    <ui:inputText label="Expense Name" value="{!v.expenseName}"/>
</aura:component>
```

in the component's client controller:

```
({
    expenseNameChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newValue = event.getParam("value");
        var oldValue = event.getParam("oldValue");
        alert("Expense name changed from '" + oldValue + "' to '" + newValue + "'");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

valueChange is definitely what you are looking for - are you wiring it up like this:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.items}" action="{!c.itemsChange}"/>
```

taken from http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/lightning/lightning.pdf

What error is the app (and what app are you working in?) throwing?

Comment: Definitely, the "valueChange" event can't be found and the "change" event never fires.     
`<aura:component>
 <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.items}" action="{!c.itemsChange}"/>
 <ui:inputText aura:id="items" label="Expense Name" value="My Expense" updateOn="change"/>
</aura:component>`    
` itemsChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('something is changing');
  var v = event.getParam("value");
        if (v === component.get("v.items")) {
            console.log(v.get('v.value'));
        }
}`  
I'm working on a appHostable cmp inside of SF1. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the mess but couldn't get the linebreaks working. Thanks Doug and quick question: is the AngularJS +Lightning pack you talked about in Dreamforce in github?

Comment: The code you posted does not really make sense - the ui:inputText is not wired to any component attribute or model property which means there is no 2 way data binding in place. This is similar to missing ng-model in Angular.js - not much is going to happen. Also the component does not appear to even have a v.items attribute defined on it.