# Lightning Component: Fire change event only when user changes field from UI and not when changing the field from code

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

Please refer link:
[Lightning Change Event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55714/lightning-change-event)

Suppose we are using handler as follows:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.expenseName}" action="{!c.expenseNameChanged}"/>
```

Now, It seems the handler would could the expenseNameChanged method in following two cases:

1. When User updates the expenseName field from UI (by editing some field in form)
2. If we update the field from code (may be from helper/controller component of lightning component)

Question: Is it possible that event get fired only when user updates the data from UI (option 1 above) and expenseNameChanged  method don't get cal when we update the field from code.

Comment: Are you using aura component such as `ui:inputText` ? If yes, won't using change attribute : `change="{!c.expenseNameChanged}"` would work for you?

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I am now using change attribute. Could you please refer any doc or link that explains when to use handlers and change attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible.

A simple workaround would be to set a global variable from your helper function - before you update the field, then on the handler function - check if that variable was set, and only then execute your code.