# How to get before/after information from change events

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events, onchange

I'm changing a field in my lightning component and handle the change with a default lightning change handler. I can not make use of [aura:handler name="change"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55714/lightning-change-event) since I'm in a loop, [where change events are not fired](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192801/lightning-change-event-doesnt-fire-in-loops) (already created [an issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues/128))

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.values}" var="value">
    <ui:inputNumber change="{!c.numberChanged}" value="{!value}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

In my controller I'm now trying to handle that change. But to do so, I need the the old field value. Is there anything in the retrieved event object, that contains this information? I digged deeper into the event methods and tried to output whatever I found, but there was nothing useful. Is the event technology documented somewhere in detail?

```
numberChanged: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    console.log(evt.getEventType());
    console.log(evt.getType());
    console.log(evt.getName());
    console.log(evt.getPhase());

    console.log(evt.getSource());
    console.log(evt.getSource().getEvent());
    console.log(evt.getSource().toString());
},
```

Output:

> - COMPONENT
> - ui:change
> - change
> - bubble
> - -
> - [Object with a few methods]
> - null
> - SecureComponentRef: markup://ui:inputSmartNumber {3765:949;a}{ key:    {"namespace":"MY_NAMESPACE"} }

3765:949 seems to be an internal identifier, it's not the numbers I changed.

---

EDIT1:
since I found [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm), it feels like there is more information behind the getSource(), but where is it documented?

---

EDIT2:
Added more information to make clear why `<aura:handler name="change" ...>` won'work

Comment: Looks like you'll need a custom lightning component again... :D

Comment: This link might help you? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55714/lightning-change-event

Comment: @HemantJain Awesome ! I didn't know that.

Comment: well in my case I can't use the lightning change handler, since I am in an iteration: [Lightning “change” event doesn't fire in loops](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192801/lightning-change-event-doesnt-fire-in-loops) but it's still a great answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The below link details on how to capture old and new values.

[Lightning Change Event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55714/lightning-change-event)

So we access the values in the controller as follows:

```
({
    numberChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newValue = event.getParam("value");
        var oldValue = event.getParam("oldValue");
        alert("Expense name changed from '" + oldValue + "' to '" + newValue + "'");
    }
})
```

Comment: This is a link only answer which is better suited as a comment as per [answer], please elaborate on the answer, since links can change.

Comment: as mentioned it's a good answer, thanks you! but it doesn't work for me, I updated the question.